# boost is giving me wrong UTC

Tags: boost, time

When I called

```
boost::posix_time::ptime utctime = boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time();
std::cout << "UTC time is " << boost::posix_time::to_simple_string(utctime) << std::endl;
```

boost is giving me 8:28pm while the local time is 4:28pm and UTC time should be 9:28pm. The time zone on my machine is correct. What could be the reason?

Comment: I am in NYC, and the time zone is setting on UTC-05:00(automatically adjust clock for Daylight Saving Time). And if I call local_time(), boost will give me correct one. I dont know why it is giving me wrong UTC all the time.

Comment: Have you check your OS settings? Are they correct? boost version?

Comment: I guess my OS setting is correct. I have added a comment above. boost version is 1.53.0.